# Python: get every possible combination of weights for a portfolio

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I think this problem can be solved using either itertools or cartesian, but I'm fairly new to Python and am struggling to use these:

I have a portfolio of 5 stocks, where each stock can have a weighting of -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2 or 0.4, with weightings adding up to 0. How do I create a function that produces a list of every possible combination of weights. e.g. [-0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0]... etc

Ideally, the function would work for n stocks, as I will eventually want to do the same process for 50 stocks.

edit: To clarify, I'm looking for all combinations of length n (in this case 5), summing to 0. **The values can repeat**: e.g: [0.2, 0.2, -0.4, 0, 0], [ 0.4, 0, -0.2, -0.2, 0.4], [0,0,0,0.2,-0.2], [0, 0.4, -0.4, 0.2, -0.2] etc. So [0,0,0,0,0] would be a possible combination. The fact that there are 5 possible weightings and 5 stocks is a coincidence (which i should have avoided!), this same question could be with 5 possible weightings and 3 stocks or 7 stocks. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want each list that's produced to have a length of _n_ and to have a sum of zero?

Comment: Judging from people's answers, there is some room for interpretation in this question. Could you list a few more combinations just to make sure we're understanding this correctly before we start writing code?

Comment: I doubt that your computer can handle the same process for 50 stocks, regardless of how you generate them. Clearly the first 25 values can be anything (just set the remaining 25 to -1 times each of them to sum to 0), which is already `5**25` things to iterate over, which is about `10**18`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop  but isn't it possible with a generator rather than list construction?

Comment: @Chris_Rands: it's not memory, it's time: my computer doesn't have time to create a billion billion Python objects before I junk it! To cover 50 stocks the questioner either needs some humongous distributed processing grid (and even then I haven't worked how big the real number is, `10**18` is a *very* loose lower bound), or a different algorithm that doesn't rely on examining every possible weighting.

Comment: Even if a generator yields 1 list per nanosecond, it's going to take over 30 years to produce `10**18` items. `5**25` nanoseconds is somewhat shorter: around 9.44 years. OTOH, one Python instruction will take more than a nanosecond to execute unless you have a _very_ fast machine. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: oops, good point, I can't count. `5**25` is order `10**17`, not 18. But `10**18` is still a very loose lower bound, since there are on average a heck of a lot more than three ways to choose the last 25 items, given the first 25.

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking for all combinations of length n (in this case 5), summing to 0: e.g: [0.2, 0.2, -0.4, 0, 0], [ 0.4, 0, -0.2, -0.2, 0.4], [0,0,0,0.2,-0.2], [0, 0.4, -0.4, 0.2, -0.2] etc.

Comment: Hmmm, actually, I wonder if we are not missing something here.  1.  you need to take the OPs 5 entries and add up their weightings to 0.   You can do that in order and keep running track of where your 0-offset is at.  So, for example, -4 +2 +2 0 0 (sorry, skipping stupid decimals).  2.  *Then* you permute that result to all possible orders of those 5 weights, because the sum will still be zero regardless.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been -4, 0, 0, +2, +2 above.  For #1, maybe each time you pick a number on the left, you could do a recursive call of your function, with as params the number of remaining weights and the condition that it needs to sum up to -1 current_sum.  So, at -4, 0 picked already you would call func(weights, entries=3, tgt=+4).  Actually, if you are doing in order, you can only pick from 0, +2, +2 on that call, since -4 and -2 are already "used up", being greater than 0, your last pick.  func(weights=[0,+2,+4]...) then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, although it's not really efficient.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import itertools

# possible optimization: use integers rather than Decimal
weights = [Decimal("-0.4"), Decimal("-0.2"), Decimal(0), Decimal("0.2"), Decimal("0.4")]

def possible_weightings(n = 5, target = 0):
    for all_bar_one in itertools.product(weights, repeat = n - 1):
        final = target - sum(all_bar_one)
        if final in weights:
            yield all_bar_one + (final,)
```

I repeat from comments, you *cannot* do this for `n = 50`. The code yields the right values, but there isn't time in the universe to iterate over all the possible weightings.

This code isn't brilliant. It does some unnecessary work examining cases where, for example, the sum of all but the first two is already greater than 0.8 and so there's no point separately checking all the possibilities for the first of those two.

So, this does `n = 5` in nearly no time, but there is some value of `n` where this code becomes infeasibly slow, and you could get further with better code. You still won't get to 50. I'm too lazy to write that better code, but basically instead of `all_bar_one` you can make recursive calls to `possible_weightings` with successively smaller values of `n` and a value of `target` equal to the target you were given, minus the sum you have so far. Then prune all the branches you don't need to take, by bailing out early in cases where `target` is too large (positive or negative) to be reached using only `n` values.

Comment: Thanks Steve this does exactly what I'm looking for. I'll have to think about the problem of going to n=50. Perhaps I should only specify 2 possible weights (positive or negative) and do it in steps. Essentially I'm doing monte carlo simulations and trying to work out what set of weights gives the best results (on average). In an ideal world this would be done in one step, but I guess I'm limited by the computer power I have.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the values can repeat, but all have to sum to zero, therefore the solution might be:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> weights = [-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4]
>>> result = (com for com in permutations(weights) if sum(com)==0)
>>> for i in result: print(i)
```

---

edit:
you might use `product` as @Steve Jassop suggested.

```
combi = (i for i in itertools.product(weights, repeat= len(weights)) if not sum(i))
for c in combi:
    print(c)
```

Comment: Thanks Juraj, this seems close but not exactly what i'm after as it does not seem to list all possible combinations. e.g it does not list [0,0,0,0,0]. Also, how can I adjust this so it does the same for 6 stocks (or n stocks?). i.e. weights can still only be either -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2 or 0.4, but there are n number of stocks this time. Thanks

Comment: You can try to use `combinations_with_replacement(weights, len(weights))` instead of `permutations`. However you will only get combinations not variations, i.e. the order is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I like using the `filter` function:

```
from itertools import permutations
w = [-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4] 

def foo(w):
    perms = list(permutations(w))
    sum0 = filter(lambda x: sum(x)==0, perms)
    return sum0

print foo(w)
```

Comment: Except as I understand the question it's not `permutations(w)`, it's `product(w, repeat=5)`. Observe that one expected output is `[-0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0]`. This is *not* a permutation of `w`, but it is "5 weightings of -0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2 or 0.4, with weightings adding up to 0". All the permutations of `w` are solutions (since they all have the same sum), but you also need to generate the solutions that use the same number more than once.

Comment: Although it's currently not clear what the OP wants it can't be what your code produces, for the reason mentioned by Steve. Also, your code doesn't make much sense. Why bother summing each permutation? They're all going to have the same sum (zero). And why are you wasting RAM collecting the permutations into a list before filtering them? FWIW, in Python 3 `filter` returns an iterable not a list, but hopefully that's not an issue.

Comment: Agreed, permutations is not the way to go. From the discussions it is a too big space to scan like that and use filter.

Answer (score 0):

Different approach.

## 1 Figure out all sequences of the weights that add up to zero, in order.

for example, these are some possibilities (using whole numbers to type less):
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[-4, 0, 0, +2, +2]
[-4, 0, 0, 0, +4]

[-4, +4, 0, 0, 0]  is incorrect because weights are not picked in order.

## 2 Permute what you got above, because the permutations will add up to zero as well.

This is where you'd get your [-4, 0, 0, 0, +4] **and** [-4, +4, 0, 0, 0]

OK, being lazy.  I am going to pseudo-code/comment-code a good deal of my solution.  Not that strong at recursion, the stuff is too tricky to code quickly and I have doubts that this type of solution scales up to 50.

i.e. I don't think I am right, but it might give someone else an idea.

```
def find_solution(weights, length, last_pick, target_sum):

    # returns a list of solutions, in growing order, of weights adding up to the target_sum

    # weights are the sequence of possible weights - IN ORDER, NO REPEATS
    # length is how many weights we are adding up
    # last_pick - the weight picked by the caller 
    # target_sum is what we are aiming for, which will always be >=0

    solutions = []

    if length > 1:

        #since we are picking in order, having picked 0 "disqualifies" -4 and -2.
        if last_pick > weights[0]:
            weights = [w for w in weights if w >= last_pick]

        #all remaining weights are possible
        for weight in weights:
            child_target_sum = target_sum + weight

            #basic idea, we are picking in growing order
            #if we start out picking +2 in a [-4,-2,0,+2,+4] list in order, then we are constrained to finding -2
            #with just 2 and 4 as choices.  won't work.
            if child_target_sum <= 0:
                break

            child_solutions = find_solution(weights, length=length-1, last_pick=weight, target_sum=child_target_sum)

            [solutions.append([weight] + child ) for child in child_solutions if child_solution]

    else:
        #only 1 item to pick left, so it has be the target_sum
        if target_sum in weights:
            return [[target_sum]]

    return solutions

weights = list(set(weights))
weights.sort()

#those are not permutated yet
solutions = find_solutions(weights, len(solution), -999999999, 0)

permutated = []
for solution in solutions:
   permutated.extend(itertools.permutations(solution))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want a list of all the combinations, use `itertools.combinations`:

```
w = [-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4]
l = len(w)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in xrange(1, l+1):
        for p in itertools.combinations(w, i):
            print p
```

If you want to count the different weights that can be created with these combinations, it's a bit more complicated.

First, you generate permutations with 1, 2, 3, ... elements. Then you take the sum of them. Then you add the sum to the set (will no do anything if the number is already present, very fast operation). Finally you convert to a list and sort it.

```
from itertools import combinations

def round_it(n, p):
    """rounds n, to have maximum p figures to the right of the comma"""
    return int((10**p)*n)/float(10**p)

w = [-0.4, -0.2, 0, 0.2, 0.4]
l = len(w)
res = set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in xrange(1, l+1):
        for p in combinations(w, i):
            res.add(round_it(sum(p), 10))  # rounding necessary to avoid artifacts

    print sorted(list(res))
```

Answer (score -3):

Is this what you are looking for:
if `L =  [-0.4, 0.2, 0, 0.2, 0]`

```
AllCombi = itertools.permutations(L)

for each in AllCombi:
    print each
```